# How does Iconv handle endianness?

Tags: macos, unix, unicode, endian

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16le | od -x
```

produces what seems to me like a big-endian result

```
0068    0065    006c    006c    006f    000a
```

whereas the same line without the `le` produces, on a utf16le system (OS X)

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | od -x

fffe    6800    6500    6c00    6c00    6f00    0a00
```

Does `od -x` change the endianness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16le | hexdump -C
00000000  68 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00  6f 00 0a 00              |h.e.l.l.o...|
```

```
$ echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16le | od -t x1
0000000 68 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 0a 00
```

The question is how 'od' handles endianness. When you're asking it to display **units larger than a single byte** (`-x` displays 16-bit words), it will default to whatever is native for the system it's running on.

Your macOS is probably running on Intel x86_64 CPU which is little-endian, meaning that bytes `{0x68, 0x00}` indeed represent the 16-bit number `0x0068` when they're decoded by 'od'.